# Refire a stopped Flex event

Tags: apache-flex, events

I have several event listeners configured to listen for a click event on a control.

I don't know if this is a correct assumption, but I believe I have one configured to listen "first".  After the first listener catches the event, it will pass control to the remaining listeners (if needed).

This basically tells the user "you're trying to navigate somewhere, but you have unsaved changes, do you want to 1) save and continue 2) discard changes and continue 3) return and don't continue.

Here's the sample code for setting up the listeners

```
clickComponent.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, parentComponent.saveChanges);
clickComponent.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, continueOn);
```

Here's where I catch the event in parentComponent

```
private var unsavedEvent:Event = null;

public function saveChanges(e:Event):void {

    if (unsavedEvent == null) {

        unsavedEvent = e;
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();

        Alert.buttonWidth = 150;
        Alert.noLabel = "Discard Changes";
        Alert.yesLabel = "Save Changes";
        Alert.cancelLabel = "Return";

        var alert:Alert = Alert.show(
            "You have unsaved changes!  What would you like to do?                       ",
            "Save?",
            Alert.NO | Alert.YES | Alert.CANCEL, 
            this, 
            handleUnsavedResponse, 
            null, 
            Alert.YES);
    }
}

private function handleUnsavedResponse(evt:CloseEvent):void {

    var takeAdditionalAction:Boolean = false;

    if(evt.detail == Alert.YES) {
        save();
        takeAdditionalAction = true;
    } else if(evt.detail == Alert.NO) {
        discard();      
        takeAdditionalAction = true;
    }

    if (takeAdditionalAction) {
        dispatchEvent(unsavedEvent.clone()); // rethrow the event we caught.  not WORKING
    }

    unsavedEvent = null; //reset the saved event
}
```

The call for `dispatchEvent(unsavedEvent.clone());` doesn't seem to work (or at least the event is not being captured by `continueOn`) At first I tried redispatching the event without the `clone()` call, but that didn't work either.

Can I do this?  Is there a better way?

Comment: Can you clarify?  The code that's supposed to be handling the mouse event isn't listed in your code, and you're not showing where your unsavedEvent is originating.

Comment: @Amy - sorry.  I modified the listener target, but forgot to edit the corresponding method name when I pasted it in (fixed now).  unsavedEvent is the event coming into the saveChanges method.  I save it so I can refire it later if needed (at least that was the plan).  That is event is fired when a user click on a component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! I needed `unsavedEvent.target.dispatchEvent(unsavedEvent.clone());` instead of `dispatchEvent(unsavedEvent.clone());`

I'm thinking that rethrowing the event also changes the target (i.e. to parentComponent from clickComponent), which would explain why my other listener wasn't responding to the event in the original code.

Comment: Unless you stop the event (event.stopImmediatePropogation), all listeners for that event should fire without your having to dispatch it again. If this is not what you are seeing in your code, you probably have a larger problem that is not exposed in what you posted.

Comment: @Amy - I am using stopImmediatePropogation.  It's in the saveChanges method.  I want to do that as I want the ask the user to save their changes before moving on.

Comment: OK, I missed seeing that.  You don't actually need to clone the event...when you dispatch the same event that has already been dispatched, clone gets called under the hood. For more details, see http://www.developria.com/2009/12/can-event-performance-be-impro.html